# Python generators, adding two arrays of numbers: am I executing this properly?

Tags: python, generator, lazy-evaluation

I'm still a little hazy on the concept of generators. I want to make a generator function that takes in two arrays of numbers and adds the values at the corresponding indexes. I've got something that works, I'm just not sure if I'm properly doing this with lazy evaluation (i.e. properly using the generator). Can someone tell me if this is indeed the correct way to use the generator, or correct me if I'm doing it wrong?

```
def add(a1,a2):
    i = 0
    while i < len(a1):
        yield a1[i]+a2[i]
        i += 1
```

Comment: Your function name broke my brain.

Comment: Yeah... it's pretty early in the morning over here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is a perfectly good generator. Are you sure `add` is a good name for it?

`zip` helps you to write this more succinctly

```
def add(a1, a2):
    for i,j in zip(a1, a2):
        yield i*j
```

you can also inline the generator as a generator expression

```
(i*j for i,j in zip(a1, a2))
```

If you are using Python2 you should use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` because `zip` isn't lazy in Python2

Comment: Yeah, but is my generator correct? That's kind of what I want to know

Comment: `zip()` is gonna lose the laziness though. no point in using a generator if you're going to make a whole list anyway.

Comment: @kindall, as you mention in your answer - it depends on which version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without the index like so:

```
from itertools import izip

def mult(list1, list2):
    for item1, item2 in izip(list1, list2):
       yield item1 + item2
```

In Python 3 you don't need the `import` and can just use `zip()`, as `zip()` is lazy in Python 3.

But yes, the way you have it is the general idea.